# Zip File error "header is corrupt" when i am adding exta field into header using java ZipEntry Class

Tags: header, zip, compression, corruption, corrupt

I set `Content Type=text/xml` in extra field of header while compressing. Below is my header.

```
PK�*�H27664.040.678.FI00091710.xmlContent Type=text/xml
```

It gives me error while decompressing validation fails "Header is corrupt".

When removing the extra field  `Content Type=text/xml`  everything works fine.
I need to set header extra field as it s necessary for me. Can someone help me how I can proceed it without getting error with extra field.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda for editing.

Comment: where you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The extra field itself has an internal format that you are required to adhere to. From the [PKWare appnote](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT):

```
 4.5.1 In order to allow different programs and different types
   of information to be stored in the 'extra' field in .ZIP
   files, the following structure MUST be used for all
   programs storing data in this field:

       header1+data1 + header2+data2 . . .

   Each header should consist of:

       Header ID - 2 bytes
       Data Size - 2 bytes

   Note: all fields stored in Intel low-byte/high-byte order.

   The Header ID field indicates the type of data that is in
   the following data block.

   Header IDs of 0 thru 31 are reserved for use by PKWARE.
   The remaining IDs can be used by third party vendors for
   proprietary usage.

   4.5.2 The current Header ID mappings defined by PKWARE are:

      0x0001        Zip64 extended information extra field
      0x0007        AV Info
      0x0008        Reserved for extended language encoding data (PFS)
                    (see APPENDIX D)
      0x0009        OS/2
      0x000a        NTFS 
      0x000c        OpenVMS
      0x000d        UNIX
      0x000e        Reserved for file stream and fork descriptors
      0x000f        Patch Descriptor
      0x0014        PKCS#7 Store for X.509 Certificates
      0x0015        X.509 Certificate ID and Signature for 
                    individual file
      0x0016        X.509 Certificate ID for Central Directory
      0x0017        Strong Encryption Header
      0x0018        Record Management Controls
      0x0019        PKCS#7 Encryption Recipient Certificate List
      0x0065        IBM S/390 (Z390), AS/400 (I400) attributes 
                    - uncompressed
      0x0066        Reserved for IBM S/390 (Z390), AS/400 (I400) 
                    attributes - compressed
      0x4690        POSZIP 4690 (reserved)
```

So you need to make up a header ID, and use that and a data size preceding your text.

Comment: Thanks, Mark!! This is really helpful to understanding header format, I have doubt regarding the header ID, header ID  is automatically generate while compressing file as per my understanding ,so how we can add header ID when adding extra field.

Comment: Just make up your own header ID. Pick a number between 32 and 65535.

Comment: Hi @Mark ,Thanks for this i tried with adding Header ID ,but still getting same error as header is corrupt. i think now error is related between two header. can you tell me what is the separator between two header.In my case in header       
`PK�*�H27664.040.678.FI00091710.xmlContent Type=text/xml`  `PK�*�H27664.040.678.FI00091710.xml` and `Content Type=text/xml` there should be separator between them to separate.can you tell me what could be seprator.

Comment: I can't tell anything from binary files rendered as text. If you want to provide binary file contents, you need to encode them using hex or base64.

Comment: I still not able to get the right answer, i stuck how to modify header i tried to inserting some hex or base 64 data between `PK�*�H27664.040.678.FI00091710.xml `and `Content Type=text/xml ` but still getting same error as header is corrupt,do u @Mark any idea how to modify header

Comment: You're still not getting the fact that you can't paste binary as text here and expect anyone to be able to help you. You need to convert it to hexadecimal or base64 or some encoding that can be represented as text and then converted back to the original binary.